# How to parse .json file with a gradle task and get the json data from it?

Tags: android, json, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Is there a way where in I can parse a xyz.json file with help of a gradle task and get all the individual json data inside it? for eg. I want to parse this data which is stored in a xyz.json file in my assets folder and get all the values inside it, eg. get the value of "type".

```
{
  "type":"xyz",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "type": "pqr"
    },
    "bar": {
      "type": "abc"
    },
    "baz": {
      "type": "lmo"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can create a gradle task like this

```
gradle myTask{
 doLast{
  def inputFile = new File("xyz.json")
  def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputFile.text)
  def labels = json.properties.foo.type //This will return "pqr"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to parse a `json` file in `build.gradle.kts` do as follows:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
val VersionsMap: Map<String, String> by extra {
    JsonSlurper().parse(file("xyz.json")) as Map<String, String>
}
val value = VersionMap.get("key")
```

Answer (score -3):

Gradle build scripts are just Groovy scripts.  Read the Gradle User Guide to learn how to write custom tasks, and use the [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) class to parse your json file.