# How to parse json file in android gradle file

Tags: android, json, android-gradle-plugin

Is there any way to parse json file in Android gradle file? 
I tried [How to parse .json file with a gradle task and get the json data from it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37824883/how-to-parse-json-file-with-a-gradle-task-and-get-the-json-data-from-it/37825593) but it's not supported in latest Android google maven.

Answer (score 0):

You can use full package name of JsonSlurper as `groovy.json.JsonSlurper()` and it'll work. So the code will be as below:

```
def path = projectDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/path/to/your/file.json"
def inputFile = new File(path)
jsonFile = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(inputFile.text)
println "Get any info as : \n $jsonFile.someObject.someKey"
```